# Showing that $f = 0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a real-valued, Borel measurable and integrable function on $[0,1]$. Suppose that $\int_A f = 0$ for all Borel subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ with measure $\frac12$. Prove that $f = 0$ a.e.

This is fairly trivial when $f$ is non-negative as $\int_{[0,1]}f = \int_{(0,\frac12)}f+\int_{(\frac12,1)}f = 0$ so on $(0,\frac12)$ $f$ is 0 a.e. and the same with the other interval. Then the point sets have measure $0$ and that gives the result.

I can't figure out how to get the desired result for generic $f$ however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is generic, then decompose $f$ into its positive and negative parts, $f=f_+-f_-$ where both $f_+$ and $f_-$ are positive. Consider the three sets
$$\begin{align} A&=\{x\colon f_+(x)\neq 0\}\\
B&=\{x\colon f_-(x)\neq 0\}\\
C&=\{x\colon f_+(x)=f_-(x)=0\}\end{align}$$
Now $A,B,C$ are disjoint and $[0,1]=A\cup B\cup C$, so one of $A\cup C$ and $B$ has measure greater than (or equal to) $\frac{1}{2}$. Now apply what you've already done a couple of times...

Comment: How do we know that $A, B$ and $C$ are Borel?

Comment: @ItsNotMeItsYou $A,B,$ and $C$ are Borel because they are the inverse images of Borel sets and $f$ is assumed to be Borel-measuarable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,B \subset [0,1]$ be Borel sets with the property that both $|A| = |B| < 1/4$.

Then $|A \cup B| < \frac 12$, so there exists a set $E \subset [0,1] \setminus (A \cup B)$ with the property that $|E \cup A| = |E \cup B| = 1/2$. Then 
$$ \int_E f + \int_A f = \int_{E \cup A} f = 0 = \int_{E \cup B} f = \int_E f + \int_B f$$
so that
$$
\int_A f = \int_B f.
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this will get us $f=0$ a.e.